# Windows 10 Pro lockscreen mass change

Tags: windows-10, powershell, group-policy

I'm search way to change lockscreen image on *Windows 10 Pro amd64* workstations in domain.

**I found than group policy option work only on Enterprise version at least in 1607 and 1703 releases.**

Registry changes takes no effect.

Changes from PowerShell not posible bacause of [SetImageFileAsync](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.userprofile.lockscreen) method requires async file operation which not implemented in PowerShell.

In [github repo](https://github.com/Sauler/PowershellUtils) there solution with [precompiled dll](https://github.com/rkeithhill/PoshWinRT) but this dll can't load on my OS with error:

> Add-Type : Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Users\kardash.CORP\Downloads\PoshWinRT.dll' or one of its depend encies. Operation is not supported. 
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515) At line:1 char:1
>   + Add-Type -Path PoshWinRT.dll
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-Type], FileLoadException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileLoadException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand

and I have no Visual Studio to compile this dll myself from sources.

Other [solution](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/5fglby/powershell_to_set_windows_10_lockscreen/daoepvj/?st=j85h6kep&sh=324628b6) has two problems:

1. It will not work if user already change image (it changes default images)
2. It changes file acl on system files.

Is there any othe way to do it? May be any commend-line utility?

Comment: You can force a specific default lock screen image through a gpo: **Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Control Panel > Personalization > Force a specific default lock screen image.** It looks like it should be possible, even though you're not using an Enterprise version of Windows 10.

Comment: @Bungicasse You should post this as an answer.

Comment: There's not much point in answering it if it is not the correct answer.. @root

Comment: @Bungicasse In what way does your comment not answer the question?

Comment: @root it's do not work in Windows 10 Pro. Tested.

Comment: That background is weird, try this (https://superuser.com/questions/1813903/lock-screen-picture-change-to-default-automatically-after-restart/1813936#1813936 ,check Krishna18 comment), found it also somewhere in registry, it had hashed path, and can be changed that way too. I personally deploy it with MDT so its present from start of win installation.

Answer (score 0):

I also went through all these paths trying to change LockScreen with Powershell script.  Ran into the same obstacles as you described.  Finally solved with Registry change by creating new key in path as described in blogpost: https://abcdeployment.wordpress.com/2017/04/20/how-to-set-custom-backgrounds-for-desktop-and-lockscreen-in-windows-10-creators-update-v1703-with-powershell/

Create new Registry key at: Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Curre‌​ntVersion\Personaliz‌​ationCSP. Then for this key create strings LockScreenImagePath, LockScreenImageUrl with data set to absolute path of your image. Then set a DWORD, name to LockScreenImageStatus, its value to 1.

Blogger's example PS Script on Onedrive: https://1drv.ms/t/s!AljjQEIEs7p2jWGOBHlScNgjX4-F
Verified that it worked on my Windows 10 Pro version 1709

Comment: You link does not work.  Which is the reason all relevant information should be contained within the body of your answer.

Comment: Use powershell to create new Registry key at: Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PersonalizationCSP.  Then for this key create LockScreenImagePath,LockScreenImageUrl with data set to absolute path of your image. Then set a DWORD, name to LockScreenImageStatus value to 1.

Comment: Why did you submit that as a comment?  All relevant information should be contained within the body of the answer not submitted as a comment.