# Lock Screen Picture change to default automatically after restart

Tags: windows, windows-10, desktop-customization

I am unable to change my lock screen wallpaper. It just keeps going back to the default wallpaper with green mountains.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anLWq.png)

whenever i change lockscreen wallpaper that is shown when we enter password after starting of pc i have tried several method online shown like:

- Make changes in Group Policy and run gpupdate /force The Group Policy
  has been updated, but I still can't change the lock screen wallpaper.
- Turn off syncing
- Open a photo using the Photos app and in the menu at the upper-right,
  select "Set as", then choose "Set as lock screen"

pc specs:

- win10
- high end pc

Answer (score 0):

Set lock screen is not the same as default lock image.
Aside ton of advice's you will find about how to replace it(i think it was backgroundDefault.jpg for default name and its at %windir%\System32\oobe\backgrounds), there is no guarantee it will work after next update(or even per device, it acts up for whatever MS reason).

Instead, why not simply replace the image, should be somewhere around "C:\WINDOWS\Web"?

Comment: tried replacing image at C:\WINDOWS\Web but still same condition

Comment: Can you check in registry do you have key Personalization;
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Personalization

and if you did something for your lock screen like link below;
https://v2cloud.com/tutorials/how-to-change-wallpaper-for-all-users-at-once

Comment: I've played around with this a lot in the past, and despite being able to get the lock screen wallpaper slideshow successfully changed over, it never seems to stick. I'm very interested to see if anyone can come up with permanent solutions to this, as it would be very useful to have our corporate images on the lock screens for all of our workstations in the company.

Comment: For you things are kind of easy,...

Create "layout" from themes(and save) and depending on the way you install OS(i use MDT to directly apply themes, not gpo), than you would need to edit hive for "%systemdrive%\Users\Default\NTUSER.DAT" and add that info, note to also add those themes into respective themes path in Default\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Themes .

Comment: finall after 1 month of research got the way to change the wallpaper you see when pc start: Replace your wallpaper at these: 
System data is most important and require security permission C:\Users\KunalMitra\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\SystemData
C:\Windows\Web\Screen